# Android - How to programmatically check if Firebase Analytics is currently enabled?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

When using the Android SDK for Firebase, how can one check if the Analytics is currently enabled/disabled?

I want to display a flag in app's UI if analytics is enabled, so this check must be done via an SDK's call.

I imagined I can easliy find an isEnabled() in SDK's API but could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

This disables or enables the GA for Firebase when added to the Manifest file depending on the value parameter.

You can write code to check this data in the manifest.

```
try {
    ApplicationInfo appinfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Bundle bundle = appinfo.metaData;
    String analytics_enabled = bundle.getString("firebase_analytics_collection_enabled");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());         
}
```

Wrapping this code in a Boolean method or just extracting the value stored in the variable to be displayed on the UI would do it for you.

Comment: I think that this is a bad idea.
The manifest flag sets a default value for whether it should be enabled/not.
That is just a default value, on the other hand the analytics SDK has a method which allows you to dynamically enable it/disable it. And using this method overrides the default value from the manifest, and it persists across app restarts.

So, checking for the manifest value is not the same as checking for whether it's enabled/disabled in real time...
I think the OP is looking for a way to do a check for the current state, and not the initial default value.